# order by first day of the week oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT last_name, hire_date,
       TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(hire_date),'DAY') AS "Day"
FROM   employees
ORDER BY (CASE TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(hire_date),'DAY')
               WHEN 'MONDAY'    THEN 1
               WHEN 'TUESDAY'   THEN 2
               WHEN 'WEDNESDAY' THEN 3
               WHEN 'THURSDAY'  THEN 4 
               WHEN 'FRIDAY'    THEN 5
               WHEN 'SATURDAY'  THEN 6 
               WHEN 'SUNDAY'    THEN 7   

           END) DESC
```

i need to sort by the first day of the week Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday etc but my output starts just with Monday due to DESC keyword then its random Friday, Tuesday, Thursday and so on. Its written like shit i know but how to fix it entirely?

Comment: You *probably* want to move that CASE expression into the SELECT clause, give it an alias, and order by the alias.

Comment: Try changing the case to `TO_CHAR(LAST_DAY(hiredate),'fmD')` 
See here http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

Comment: This is very similar to this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16478112/oracle-sql-sort-week-days-by-current-day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do your order by, use `TO_CHAR(hire_date, 'D')`

This will assign Sunday of the first day of the week.

You can then use a decode to send Sunday to the end of the sort:

```
select  * 
from 
employees  
ORDER BY  DECODE(to_char(hire_date, 'D'), 1, 8, to_char(hire_date, 'D')) 

1/6/2014    MONDAY   
1/20/2014   MONDAY   
1/27/2014   MONDAY   
1/13/2014   MONDAY   
1/28/2014   TUESDAY  
1/14/2014   TUESDAY  
1/7/2014    TUESDAY  
1/21/2014   TUESDAY  
1/22/2014   WEDNESDAY
1/1/2014    WEDNESDAY
1/15/2014   WEDNESDAY
1/8/2014    WEDNESDAY
1/29/2014   WEDNESDAY
1/2/2014    THURSDAY 
1/16/2014   THURSDAY 
1/9/2014    THURSDAY 
1/23/2014   THURSDAY 
1/30/2014   THURSDAY 
1/24/2014   FRIDAY   
1/31/2014   FRIDAY   
1/10/2014   FRIDAY   
1/3/2014    FRIDAY   
1/17/2014   FRIDAY   
1/11/2014   SATURDAY 
1/18/2014   SATURDAY 
1/25/2014   SATURDAY 
1/4/2014    SATURDAY 
1/12/2014   SUNDAY   
1/19/2014   SUNDAY   
1/26/2014   SUNDAY   
1/5/2014    SUNDAY
```